# How do I handle linking a record to another table?

Tags: ms-access, relational-database, ms-access-2016

I'm very new to Access and my teacher is... hard to follow. So I feel like there's something pretty basic I'm probably missing here. I think the biggest problem I'm having with this question is that I'm struggling to find the words to communicate what I actually need to do, which is really putting a damper on my google-fu.

In terms of what I *think* I want to do, I want to make a record reference another table in its entirety.

```
Main
+----+-------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
| PK | Name  | Phone# | [...] |           Cards            |
+----+-------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
|  1 | Bob   | [...]  | [...] | < Reference to 2nd table > |
|  2 | Harry | [...]  | [...] | [...]                      |
|  3 | Ted   | [...]  | [...] | [...]                      |
+----+-------+--------+-------+----------------------------+

Bob's Cards
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
| PK |  Card Name  | Condition | Year  | Price | [...] |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | Big Slugger | Mint      | 1987  | .20   | [...] |
|  2 | Quick Pete  | [...]     | [...] | [...] | [...] |
|  3 | Mac Donald  | [...]     | [...] | [...] | [...] |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

This would necessitate an entire new table for each record in the main table though, if it's even possible.

But the only alternative solution I can think of is to add 'Card1, Condition1, [...], Card2, Condition2, [...], Card3, [...]' fields to the main table and having to add another set of fields any time someone increases the maximum number of cards stored.

So I'm sort of left believing there is some other approach I should be taking that our teacher has failed to properly explain. We haven't even touched on forms and reports yet so I don't need to worry about working them in.

Any pointers?

(Also, the entirety of this data and structure is only a rough facsimile of my own, as I'd rather learn how to do it and apply it myself than be like 'here's my data, pls fix.')

Comment: This depends on a number of things, however to keep it simple you would normally add one field to the cards table, with an number data type called CardOwnerID. In your example it would be 1 indicating Bob. This is known as a foreign key. (FK) - However if you have a table of cards and multiple possible owners then you need a third table - a Junction table. This would consist of the Main Person ID and the Card ID.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. So essentially I was thinking about the relationship backwards.

So my main table wouldn't contain any reference at all to the cards, and connecting a person and their contact info to a card would only come up in a report? It feels strange to leave things that way, but I guess I have to get it in my head that the main table is not an excel spreadsheet or report...

Comment: In a rational database design, they say "the whole key, and nothing but the key". Which means each record is identifyable by a key. if you want to link/represent you use the key :)

Comment: The secret is think vertical (database structure) , not horizontal (spreadsheet Structure). As a good rule of thumb any time you are adding numbers to a field Card1, Card2 etc. you have a structure problem. Fields store the data not the field itself.

Comment: @krishKM The issue would be that an entire table doesn't really have a key I can reference (?), but thanks to Minty's tip that's no longer even relevant haha.

Comment: Thanks Minty. I think maybe knowing a little excel has been more harm than help in Access so far :P

Comment: Before you describe what you think is a solution, describe your *requirement*. What about what situtations do you want to record?

Comment: If I gave you a row table 1, what would its card column tell you? For Bob you don't seem to *need* it, since you have table 2. But if you replaced the 2 by a 3 like 2 but plus a person_id then you wouldn't need the card column for anyone, as the value of the expression 'select PK, ... from 3 where person_id=*x*' is *x*'s version of 2. You do not need constraints (including FKs) to query. They are for integrity. You just need to know what a row being in a table means. *Tables* represent relation(ship)s. Queries make tables for relation(ship)s expressed per their base tables' relation(ship)s.

Comment: I've given an adapted version of what I actually need as the example, because it's a homework assignment and I didn't want my work to just be done for me. But what I actually need doesn't require queries to factor in at all because we haven't learned about them yet.

The actual assignment was to build a database for recipes. So what I have is a table for recipes and the information they pull from lookup tables, as well as a table for ingredients and their quantities/measurements (the latter of which are pulled from a lookup table as well) which reference a specific recipe each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third option successfully found in comments by the helpful Minty.

> This depends on a number of things, however to keep it simple you
>   would normally add one field to the cards table, with an number data
>   type called CardOwnerID. In your example it would be 1 indicating Bob.
>   This is known as a foreign key. (FK) - However if you have a table of
>   cards and multiple possible owners then you need a third table - a
>   Junction table. This would consist of the Main Person ID and the Card
>   ID. – Minty

Comment: You don't *need* a junction table just because multiple people can own the same card. Adding a junction table instead of adding a person id column to the second table just involves certain problematic redundancy in comparison.